# form loaded in bootstrap modal via ajax does not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal whose content (inputs of a form) is loaded from a second html document using an ajax call. I need to validate the form and for that I've tried to implement jquery validate. It works correctly if the form is not ajax loaded (see my jsbin, the plugin works and it's also doing an ajax call to validate a name), but as I need it (in a modal), it does not. The console shows: cannot read property of 'settings' of undefined.

Thanks for your help again.

This is my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/nodavibexa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Below is my script (stripped-down version):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#customerAddressForm").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name"

        }
    });

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var isAdd = $('#customerAddressForm').prop("action").split("/").pop();
        console.log(isAdd);
        if (isAdd == "shipping") {
            console.log("A");
            $('#field1').rules("add", {

                required: true,
                remote: {

                    url: "https://localhost:8443/mysite/myaccount/addresses/isExistingAddressName",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {
                        customerId: function () {
                            return $("#customerId").val();
                        }


                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("B");
            $('#field1').rules("add", {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "https://localhost:8443/mysite/myaccount/addresses/isExistingAddressName",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {
                        customerAddressId: "-10"
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $("#customerAddressForm").valid();
    });
});
```

Comment: This might be an issue where you need to attach the event handler to the newly added elements on the DOM. Meaning, on the success callback you might need to declare the `validate` function on whatever element was just added.

Comment: Yes... pay attention to the first comment.  You can only call `.validate()` **after** the form has been created/loaded.  And you're not showing us any of the code that creates or loads the modal content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it doesnt work when using $(document).ready() since the elements aren't present at the time this event is fired?

Try to use

```
$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(){ # rest of your code # });
```

Comment: I wrapped my code inside the ajaxComplete method and now the plugin is validating. Saved my day. Thanks